# Create has_many :through association in Rails 4 with building a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
def create
    @business = user.businesses.build(business_params)
    if @business.save
        business.set_logo_url
        redirect_to admin_businesses_path, flash: { notification: 'New business has been created successfully' }
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Before this code works; user "has_many" businesses and all worked good, but now user "has_many :through" and this code created a new business but not relatiionship! How can I fix this code saving this business-logic? THanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship model?

Answer (score 4):

> but now user "has_many :through"

This is the core of the issue here - Rails does *many* things well, but it cannot read minds yet

The problem you have is that you're trying to build an association which either doesn't exist, or is part of another association (the `:through`) argument. Let me explain:

---

**has_many**

When you `.build` an object - it has to be associated to the "parent" object you're working with. The `has_many` association is directly associated with the parent object, allowing you to `.build` it singularly:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :businesses
end
```

This will give you the ability to perform the following: `@user.businesses.build`

The *problem* you have now is that using `through` means your `businesses` object is not directly associated to your parent `User`- it's related *through* another object. This means that in order to build this deeper dependent object, you have first build the `through` object:

---

**through**

You've not given us your associations, but say they were like so:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :business_users
   has_many :businesses, through: : business_users
end

#app/models/business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :business_users
   has_many :users, through: :business_users
end

#app/models/business_user.rb
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :business
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you'll have to build the associations slightly differently:

```
@user.business_users.build.build_business
```

See how you not have to call the "join" model?

Before, you could just call the `businesses` association directly. But as you are going *through* another model, this will have to be built as well.

---

**Form**

Translating into a form, you'll end up with this setup:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @user = User.new
       @user.business_users.build.build_business
   end

   def create
       @user = User.new user_params
       @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:user, :params, business_users_attributes: [business_attributes: []])
   end
end
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :business_users do |bu| %>
      <%= bu.fields_for :user do |u| %>
          <%= u.text_field ... %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `:inverse_of` in your `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :business_types, inverse_of: :user #let your relationship model to be BusinessType
  has_many :businesses, :through => :business_types
  ...
end
```

Also don't forget to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your relationship model too

Answer (score 0):

Try use create instead of build like this:

```
def create
    @business = user.businesses.create(business_params)
    if @business.save
        business.set_logo_url
        redirect_to admin_businesses_path, flash: { notification: 'New business has been created successfully' }
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```